# i want my div to be under the image but it is overlapping, i cant find why

Tags: html, css

Probably very easy. But, i new to coding, this is my first personnel project. I want the list in the div to be show after the image1 and it is currently over the image

```css
.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

#list {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

ul {
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><strong>G.M.S.</strong> <br> Soudure Générale</h1>
  <img src="images/soudeur.jpg" alt="Soudeur" class="image1">
</header>

<div id="list">
  <h2>Specialités<br>Réparation et Modification</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Rampe</li>
    <li>Balcon</li>
    <li>Escalier</li>
    <li>Tourelle</li>
    <li>Cloture</li>
    <li>Grillage</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wzc4db09/

Comment: the `div` is showing already after the `image`

Comment: as firsta dvice, wrap the image into a div and use soemthign like `object-fit: contain;` so that the image will be responsive. Then, dont use `position: relative;`if you dont itnent to use `position: absolute;`for one of its child

Comment: you are right when i click on your link it is but not im my browser thats weird

Comment: i have remove the image from the header and it is now at the right place , now il try the object fit and remove the relative position, Thank you very much everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok to me. If you are a beginer as u said, you should experiment in pages like [codepen.io](https://codepen.io)
Probably your problem is caused by some other css included by the content management system or site generator you are using.
You should check the applied rules using firefox inspector, or alike in browser you are running. Maybe a float, or fix size+overflow on the general img tag or the containing header.

```css
.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

#list {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

ul {
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header> 
    <h1><strong>G.M.S.</strong> <br> Soudure Générale</h1>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oqVsHoTl.jpg" alt="Soudeur" class="image1">
</header>



<div id="list">
    <h2>Specialités<br>Réparation et Modification</h2>
    
    <ul>
        <li>Rampe</li>
        <li>Balcon</li>
        <li>Escalier</li>
        <li>Tourelle</li>
        <li>Cloture</li>
        <li>Grillage</li>
    </ul>



</div>
```